# Gem equivalent in codeigniter

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter. Like we have gems in Ruby on rails which provide ready-made functionalities, do we have something similar in Codeigniter framework ?

Comment: kindly explain the negative marks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has Composer which is more or less the same: https://getcomposer.org/